# SupportMapFragment into DialogFragment error on inflate map

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, supportmapfragment

I'm writing a class to show up a `SupportMapFragment` into a `DialogFragment` as shown. The problem is that I'm getting an error "Inflating class fragment", despite of have imported `import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;`.

layout/mapa.xml:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   android:orientation="vertical" >
     <fragment android:id="@+mapa/mapa" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="300dp" class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
package br.com.globalinterativa.uteis;

import br.com.globalinterativa.rcf.R;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;


public class SupMapFragmentDF extends DialogFragment implements OnMapClickListener,     OnMapLongClickListener {

private LatLng latLong;
private int actionCode;
private CallBackMethods returnn;

public SupMapFragmentDF(CallBackMethods returnn, int actionCode){
    this.returnn = returnn;
    this.actionCode=actionCode;
}

public interface CallBackMethods {
    public abstract void onLatLongSetados(LatLng latLong, int actionCode);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            returnn.onLatLongSetados(latLong, actionCode);
        }
    });
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa, null) );
    return builder.create();
}   
public static void inicializa(DatePickerDialogFragment dp, Bundle b, FragmentManager fm) {

}
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    this.latLong = latLong;
}
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    this.latLong = latLong;
}
}
```

Comment: can you please and the stack trace to the question?

Comment: Did you get any success implementing this? I'm facing the same problem here...

Comment: Santirivera, unfortunately not. I solved that problem changing my approach, using a View instead of DialogFragment.